# How to retrieve current server FQDN in a java class

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

I need to compose a dynamic URL based on current host running the web application.
I have a backgrund process launched on startup via *ServletContextListener*.

This thread has to send emails to customers with a registration ticket. In the email text I need to print the complete URL to my webapp and the servlet. Lets say those emails like *"click here to confirm your subscription or copy&paste blabla...."*

How my I obtain the FQDN of my running webapp? 
It's not a servlet so I cannot relay on a *HttpServletRequest* instance and the server has many virtual hosts.

Here is where I launch the thread:

```
public class Initializer implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        Log.addItem("SYSTEM START");

        PasswordRecoveryListener pwlisten = new PasswordRecoveryListener(1000 * 60 * 1);
        pwlisten.start();
    }
}
```

In **arg0.getServletContext().getContextPath()** I found nothing but the path.

I looked for the hostname in the Context (where I have other constants) but without success.

Comment: I guess you can't.....you can't be sure what the "external" FQDN will be inside your web app. You could maybe get it from a request (or the possible FQDN would be in the request)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName()

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg I fear you're right, speaking of a multi virtual host environment its impossible to programmatically determine the FQDN without an external Request...

Comment: Using **InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()** as suggested by @Bart will return the *hostname* configured on the server wich has nothing in common with the name of the virtual host but at least I can distinguish development system (returns localhost) from production and use the context to store a static (but customizable) name. Is not what I wanted but it's an acceptable improvement